# How to get Firebase Node children

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm pretty new to firebase on JavaScript so it's most likely a silly and possibly a duplicate question but I'm having trouble trying to get these two children from each "Task". I tried getting access of the task's properties with ["Task"] and ["Status"] but it's showing undefined for me.

[image: Firebase Database]

```
var members = projectRef.child("Data").child("Members").orderByKey().startAt(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).once('value').then(function(snapshot) // Gets all members with their data
{
    var data = [];
    
        var taskArray = [];
    
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) // Goes to each member
        {
                var childData = childSnapshot.val(); // Gets all of the member's children as an object from the childSnapshot
    
                var childTasks = childData.Tasks;

        
                if(childTasks)
                {
                      console.log(childTasks);

                      for (task in childTasks)
                      {
                           console.log(task);
                           console.log(task["Status"]);
                           console.log(task["Task"]);
                      }
                }
    
                data.push(childData);
         });

    
         return data;                    
});
```

Results for childTasks

```
{
  '-ME2IdeYYwHqWJ82ynob': { Status: 'Not completed', Task: 'flsdjlfksdjflksd' },
  '-ME5YHsoMVxX5sTq5RVA': { Status: 'Not completed', Task: 'lfjsdlkfjslkdfjlksf' },
  '-ME5YKh30-rs_Fq2QhBU': { Status: 'Not completed', Task: 'sflksdjfsklfjdksljsdlf' }
}
```

Results for the task, task["Status"], and task["Task"]

```
-ME2IdeYYwHqWJ82ynob
undefined
undefined
-ME5YHsoMVxX5sTq5RVA
undefined
undefined
-ME5YKh30-rs_Fq2QhBU
undefined
undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're missing a `forEach` over the lowest level repeated node type.

```
projectRef.child("Data").child("Members").orderByKey().startAt(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(memberSnapshot) {
        var tasksSnapshot = memberSnapshot.child("Tasks");

        tasksSnapshot.forEach(function(taskSnapshot) {
            console.log(taskSnapshot.val());
            console.log(taskSnapshot.child("Status").val());
        })
     });
});
```

Things I changed that I'd highly recommend:

- Stick to navigating snapshots as long as possible, before calling `val()`.
- Give your snapshots meaningful names, representing the entities in your JSON.

---

In general though, it seems you initial query can be replaced by a direct lookup, since it seems you want to look up the member by their UID and it's unique. By looking up the user (and their `Tasks` node( directly, you can remove another `forEach` loop, making the code even easier to read:

```
var memberRef = 
projectRef.child("Data").child("Members").child(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);
memberRef.once('value').then(function(memberSnapshot) {

    var tasksSnapshot = memberSnapshot.child("Tasks");

    tasksSnapshot.forEach(function(taskSnapshot) {
        console.log(taskSnapshot.val());
        console.log(taskSnapshot.child("Status").val());
    })
});
```

And since you only use the `Tasks` child node, you can simplify this even further to:

```
var memberRef = 
projectRef.child("Data").child("Members").child(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);
var tasksRef = memberRef.child("Tasks");
tasksRef.once('value').then(function(tasksSnapshot) {
    tasksSnapshot.forEach(function(taskSnapshot) {
        console.log(taskSnapshot.val());
        console.log(taskSnapshot.child("Status").val());
    })
});
```

Comment: The first suggestion worked for me, thank you so much. I didn't know you had to use child to access the Status and Task values so my bad.

Comment: Also, does the second suggestion only work for one member? Because what I'm trying to do is get all of the data from each member pushed into an array so I send and display it through Handlebars and wanted the current user to be the first one to be displayed (which is why I started with the currentUser's uid).

Comment: You're filtering users with `startAt(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)` right now. It doesn't start **with** that user, but it orders all nodes by their key and then starts **at** that user.

Comment: Oh I didn't even notice that, thank you. How would it be to make the current user be the first one in the array and then the rest?

Comment: That's not an operation the database can do, so you'd have to download all data (in the order you want to display most of them) and then in your application code put the current user at the front.